# how do I convert this code to unobstrusive javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my view:

```
<div class="answer">
<% tarea = 'ta' + j.to_s %>
<%= text_area_tag(tarea, nil) %>
<script>
$("<%="#"+tarea%>").change(function() { $.get("/answer", function(data){ $("<%= "#"+ tarea%>").val(data)})});
</script>
</div>
```

I am using rails3.2, and want to use UJS (I am not using a form_for). How do I do this? I tried adding :remote=>true to the text_area_tag, but that did not seem to work

Comment: Don't think you can. UJS isn't a general-purpose tool, and I doubt it can work with `change` events on a text area. Especially since your code doesn't seem to make sense... What are you doing, overwriting the content of the textarea with whatever value comes back from the server each time it changes?

Comment: I am doing additional computation on the server side based on what the user has entered in the textarea (There is addition code I did not post that changes other elements on the page based on the user's input)

Comment: But you're not posting the user's input back to the server. You're issuing a `get` request, and overwriting the value in the textbox with whatever the server sends back to you.

Comment: Also, this is really ugly: `$("<%="#"+tarea%>")`. You could write it as `$("#<%=tarea%>")`, or just modify `tarea` to be `"#ta" + j.to_s` and just write `$("<%= tarea %>")` everywhere.